# Display Ž from substring

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, locale

I extract first letter of author with substr function for navigation purposes. The author named Žižek produces akward symbol instead first letter. I ommit this issue hardcoding value if this name occurs. My db/connection is utf8, my html is utf8, my file is utf8.

```
$letter='';
foreach ($authors as $value) {
    if($letter!=substr($value->author->name, 0,1)){
         $letter=substr($value->author->name, 0,1);
     if ($value->author->name=='Žižek'){
        echo '<a name="'.strtolower($letter).'"></a><span class="vbig red">ž</span>';
    } else {
         echo '<a name="'.strtolower($letter).'"></a><span class="vbig red">'.$letter.'</span>';
    }
}
```

Can I do better than that ?

Comment: Use mb_substr - it handles multibyte strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php), [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php).

Comment: Didnt know about these function, I'll check them around 9 p.m. and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I confirm - it works, I left this problem for like 4 years.